# flutter FCM notification sound not working in release

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm struggling last few days with this. I have flutter app that should receive notification from firebase (using FCM) and play custom sound. This works fine if I run app using `flutter run` or using `flutter run --release`, but if I build app using `flutter build apk --release` and install it manually on my phone I still get notification but sound is missing, it won't even play default notification sound.

I checked if my sound is on, and if notification channels in app settings are correct.

**main.dart**

```
void main() async {
  // needed if you intend to initialize in the `main` function
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  fcm.getToken().then((value) {
    print("TOKEN:" + value);
  });

  fcm.configure(
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {},
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {},
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
       AudioCache _audioCache = AudioCache(
          prefix: "sounds/",
          fixedPlayer: AudioPlayer()..setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.STOP));

      _audioCache.play('merchant_notify.mp3');
    },
  );

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
   
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "" 
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"    
   
}
```

**androidmanifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label=""
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true">

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
       
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

       
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
       <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" /> 
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.merchant_delivery

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity



class MainActivity: FlutterActivity()  { 
}
```

Also there is sound file in `res\raw\sound.mp3`

Here is json that I send to firebase FCM:

```
{
    "registration_ids": [
       
    ],
      "notification": {
        "title": "Test notification",
        "body": "Body test",
        "android_channel_id": "channel_name",
        "channel_id": "channel_name",
        "sound": "sound",
        "priority":"high"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you finally find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I'dont really know how did I fix it. I can send you code so you can try it if you have same problem

Comment: Yes, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:keep="@raw/{filename}"/>
```

add this in the keep.xml which is inside the raw folder of the android resource directory.
while creating the release build it actually shrinks the file and changes the name so this is what i got for the solutions.

Comment: Your solution should work, will check it out, thanks!

Comment: been searching for this from few days, working perfect after reinstallation

Answer (score 2):

try this in your MainActivity.java

```
    import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;   
    import android.app.NotificationChannel;  
    import android.app.NotificationManager;  
    import android.media.AudioAttributes;  
    import android.net.Uri;  
    import android.os.Build;   
    import android.os.Bundle;   
    public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {  
@Override  
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {  
  Uri soundUri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getApplicationContext()   
.getPackageName() + "/" +  R.raw.[soundName without extension]);  
AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()   
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)    
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)   
                .build();   

        // Creating Channel   
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel([ChannelId],[ChannelName], NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
   // GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I found one solution that will (hopefully) work for you, too:

Like for you, everything worked in `flutter run --release` or `flutter run`, but not when actually building and installing a `apk-release` on my phone (A5 2017).

So I thought*: Only difference is shrinking, right? Flutter shrinks down the apk automatically (see: [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#shrinking-your-code-with-r8)), so I used the `--no-shrink` flag and now everything works fine, even with the build app.

*By thinking I mean pulling my hair for 3hours, not remotely thinking about this specific difference.

Comment: Is there any specific reason that would couse this issue? I have fixed it but don't know how, here is my MainActivitiy.kt ```class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }
} ``` I think that helped!

Comment: So Can you give me a Good Conclusion. Like, what should be the order, ex: will it be, `flutter -- no-shrink` or `flutter run --no-shrink`